# Parenting mirrored objects to bones

Tags: rigging

I designed some wings using the mirror modifier to preserve symmetry. Now, I want to manually parent it to a specific bone. For now, I first select the wings, then Shift+select the armature, then select the bone, and `Ctrl-P > Bone`. The issue is that both wings are parented to the same bone... so they can't move separately:

[image]

What is the proper way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you do it this way, separate the 2 wings in 2 separate objects. The other solution would be to join the wings to the rest of the body, select the vertices of one wing and assign them to the vertex group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control it, and same for the other wing.

Comment: Thanks, but with your solution, in any case I need to separate my wings, meaning that I won't be able to symmetrically edit my object? Also, my wings are created using a solidified curve, so I'm not sure if the second solution applies here.

Comment: If you want to keep some modifiers for the wings you can't join them to the rest of the body. WIth the first solution, you can still symmetrize, but you may need to reassign to the good vertex group

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bone-parenting is *transformation*, which will never change the shape of a single object, merely scale, rotate, or translate it.  In this case, what you're looking for is *deformation*, probably via an armature modifier, which allows you to change the shape.  However, it sounds like you're using a curve to create your wings, and curves don't have a lot of good deformation options (not weighted armature deformation, which is what you'd usually want.)  It's typical to finalize meshes before rigging, which would mean converting curves to meshes and applying modifiers; doing this would let you weight each wing to an individual wing bone, but you'd lose non-destructive editing.

However, there is something you can do, if you always want the wings to be symmetrical.  You can specify a mirror object for your mirror modifier:

[image]

Top shows our transformed curve object, like you have.  Bottom shows the same transformation, but we've specified an empty as the mirror object in the mirror modifier.  If I parent the wings to the wing bone and the empty to the body bone (or whatever, I'm not sure what you're creating) then one wing will be transformed by the wing bone, and then it will be mirrored over the body.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried your second solution actually before posting this question, but I got strange results when the character was moving its torso, but I may gave poorly parented my empty. I'm wondering, Node Geometry may be used to produce two symetrical wings from a same curve, allowing best of both world no?